# Negative or 0 second duration

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I recently came across plenty of weird videos with negative durations

firstly 0 seconds:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/397056507243528203/739081902278836234/short_video.webm

And negative duration:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/397056507243528203/739081962211377152/CorruptFile.webm

I tought it was a trick with webms but there also is a mp4:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/397056507243528203/739081981643718687/video0-21.mp4

I would love to know how I can make videos like these

Answer (score 0):

through [vencord](https://github.com/Vendicated/Vencord), you can use the "corruptmp4" plugin, i believe it corrupts mp4s with long durations to show as negative. thats all i know, hope it helped.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).